# PHP not sending variable to JS

Tags: javascript, php

I'm struggling with calling a JS function `firstLetterSearch()` using PHP, and passing a variable `$_POST['word']` to it.
I can send an int as an argument but if I send this variable then it just shows up as `{}` when I log the value to the console.

```js
function firstLetterSearch(firstLetter){
    console.log('First letter search function called');
    let abc = JSON.stringify(firstLetter);
    console.log(abc);
    if(firstLetter === 1){
        console.log('I will select word starting with A');
    } else if(firstLetter === 2){
        console.log('I will select word starting with B');
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Random Word Generator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="update.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="words.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="updateChat();">

<p id=shownword></p>

    <form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="a" id="a"/> 
          
        <input type="submit" name="word"
                class="button" value="b" id="b"/> 
    </form>
    
    <?php
    //This function gets called when button is pushed
    function postword(){
        $fp = fopen('word.txt', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, $_POST['word']);
        fclose($fp);
        

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'firstLetterSearch(';
        echo $_POST['word'];
        echo ');',
        '</script>';
        
    }
    //When the button is pushed, the function will be called
    if (isset($_POST['word'])) {
        postword();
        //return;
    }
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does `I can send an int as an argument` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code nearly works.

The part that says

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'firstLetterSearch(';
        echo $_POST['word'];
        echo ');',
        '</script>';
```

actually outputs `firstLetterSearch(a);` when you really want `firstLetterSearch("a");`

So just change it to this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
        'firstLetterSearch("';
        echo $_POST['word'];
        echo '");',
        '</script>';
```